# How to check if inputs is false or true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to see if all the input fields are true, if not add a class "false" and a border around input-field. How do I check if all the inputs are true? Now I only get one border even if its two fields that are wrong. If lastname and age is wrong, I want to add a red border around the input.

```
function inputCount() {
    var formPets = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var lastName = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
    var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
    var email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;

    for (var i = 0; i < formPets.length; i++) {

    if(firstName.value == "" || !isNaN(firstName) || firstName.length > 50)
    {
        alert("False");
        var firstNameFalse = document.getElementById("firstname");
        firstNameFalse.classList.add("false");
        return false;
    } 
    else if (lastName.value == "" || !isNaN(lastName) || lastName.length > 50){
        alert("False");
        var lastNameFalse = document.getElementById("lastname");
        lastNameFalse.classList.add("false");
        return false;
    }
    else if (age.value == "" || isNaN(age) || age.length > 0){
        alert("False");
        var ageFalse = document.getElementById("age");
        ageFalse.classList.add("false");
        return false;
    }
    else if (email.value == "" || !isNaN(email) || email.length > 50){
        alert("False");
        var emailFalse = document.getElementById("email");
        emailFalse.classList.add("false");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("OK");
    }
}
}


#firstname.false {
    border-color: red !important;
}
#lastname.false {
    border-color: red !important;
}
#age.false {
    border-color: red !important;
}
#email.false {
    border-color: red !important;
}


<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">Firstname<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"> Lastname<br>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age"> Age<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"> Email<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="inputCount()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: change all the `else if` to `if`, remove all `return` statements. If you want to return `true` or `false`, make that to a variable declared outside

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but if I did, I think you just have to change the `else if` to `if` and remove the `return` statements :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function inputCount() {
    var formPets = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
    var lastName = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
    var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
    if (firstName.value == "" || !isNaN(firstName) || firstName.length > 50) {
      var firstNameFalse = document.getElementById("firstname");
      firstNameFalse.classList.add("false");
    }
    if (lastName.value == "" || !isNaN(lastName) || lastName.length > 50) {
      var lastNameFalse = document.getElementById("lastname");
      lastNameFalse.classList.add("false");
    }
    if (age.value == "" || isNaN(age) || age.length > 0) {
      var ageFalse = document.getElementById("age");
      ageFalse.classList.add("false");
    }
    if (email.value == "" || !isNaN(email) || email.length > 50) {
      var emailFalse = document.getElementById("email");
      emailFalse.classList.add("false");
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  #firstname.false {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
  #lastname.false {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
  #age.false {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
  #email.false {
    border-color: red !important;
  }
</style>

<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />Firstname<br />
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /> Lastname<br />
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" /> Age<br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> Email<br />
<button type="submit" onclick="inputCount()">Submit</button>
```

I also removed the useless `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Issues

- No need to use a loop.
- Collect all inputs and check its validity
- Add a class `false` if not valid.
- Remove class `false` if valid

```js
function inputCount() {
  var formPets = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value;
  var lastName = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value;
  var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  var email = document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value;

  var firstNameFalse = document.getElementById("firstname");
  if (firstName.value == "" || !isNaN(firstName) || firstName.length > 50) {
    console.log("False");
    firstNameFalse.classList.add("false");
    // return false;
  } else {
    firstNameFalse.classList.remove("false");
  }

  var lastNameFalse = document.getElementById("lastname");
  if (lastName.value == "" || !isNaN(lastName) || lastName.length > 50) {
    console.log("False");
    lastNameFalse.classList.add("false");
    // return false;
  } else {
    lastNameFalse.classList.remove("false");
  }

  var ageFalse = document.getElementById("age");
  if (age.value == "" || isNaN(age.value)) {
    console.log("False");
    ageFalse.classList.add("false");
    // return false;
  } else {
    ageFalse.classList.remove("false");
  }

  var emailFalse = document.getElementById("email");
  if (email.value == "" || !isNaN(email) || email.length > 50) {
    console.log("False");
    emailFalse.classList.add("false");
    // return false;
  } else {
    emailFalse.classList.remove("false");
  }
}
```

```css
#firstname.false {
  border-color: red !important;
}

#lastname.false {
  border-color: red !important;
}

#age.false {
  border-color: red !important;
}

#email.false {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">Firstname<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"> Lastname<br>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age"> Age<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"> Email<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="inputCount()">Submit</button>
```

If can also select all the inputs with query selector `document.querySelectorAll` and check if each input if valid as done below.

```js
function inputCount() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    if (
      (input.id !== "age" && (input.value == "" || input.value.length > 50 || !isNaN(input.value))) ||
      (input.id === "age" && (input.value == "" || isNaN(input.value)))
    )  {
      input.classList.add("false");
    } else {
      input.classList.remove("false");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.false {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">Firstname<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"> Lastname<br>
<input type="text" name="age" id="age"> Age<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"> Email<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="inputCount()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorted the code as

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

const addErrorClass = element => element.classList.add("false");
const removeErrorClass = element => element.classList.remove("false");

function inputCount() {
  const formPets = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));

  formPets.forEach(element => {
    const value = element.value.trim();
    const elementName = element.name;

    if (elementName === "age")(value === "" || isNaN(value)) ? addErrorClass(element) : removeErrorClass(element);
    else if (elementName === "email")(value === "" || !isNaN(value) || !validateEmail(value)) ? addErrorClass(element) : removeErrorClass(element);
    else(value === "" || !isNaN(value) || value.length > 50) ? addErrorClass(element) : removeErrorClass(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">Firstname<br>
<input type="text" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"> Lastname<br>
<input type="text" type="number" name="age" id="age"> Age<br>
<input type="text" type="email" name="email" id="email"> Email<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="inputCount()">Submit</button>
```